# Keep quotes inside variables in heredocs (bash)

Tags: bash

I have a variable that I receive from an external service that is in JSON format, and I want to use it inside a HEREDOC. I tried to use `jq` but got a parse error. This happens because the variable inside the HEREDOC don't have quotes.

Below is an example of what happens:

```
list="[{\"a\"=\"b\"}]"

echo "out"
echo "$list"
echo "len=${#list}"

echo ""

/bin/bash <<-SHELL
    echo "in - 1"
    echo "$list"
    echo "len=${#list}"

    echo ""

    list2="$list"
    echo "in - 2"
    echo "\$list2"
    echo "len=\${#list2}"

    echo ""

    list3="[{\"a\"=\"b\"}]"
    echo "in - 3"
    echo "\$list3"
    echo "len=\${#list3}"
SHELL
```

And the output:

```
out
[{"a"="b"}]
len=11

in - 1
[{a=b}]
len=11

in - 2
[{a=b}]
len=7

in - 3
[{"a"="b"}]
len=11
```

I assume this happens because the external variables are expanded before the HEREDOC is executed, but is there a way to make HEREDOC preserve the quotes **in** the variable that was generated outside it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote the delimiter, so that no parameter expansions happen in the here document. Then pass your JSON value as an argument, rather than embedding it in the script.

```
list='[{"a"="b"}]'

echo "out"
echo "$list"
echo "len=${#list}"

echo ""

/bin/bash <<-'SHELL' -s "$list"
    echo "in - 1"
    echo "$1"
    echo "len=${#1}"
SHELL
```

The `-s` option allows you to provide arguments to a shell that reads its command from standard input, so that `"$list"` isn't mistaken for the name of the script to execute.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `-s` option for heredocs, that solves it for the example I showed. Unfortunately, it also means that all variables that I use in heredocs should be processed outside it (but in my case some of them are processed inside it). The heredoc is run inside a docker container, so some commands should be run inside it. I found that `list_in=$(printf %s "'$list'")` also solves it, but it could be considered unsafe (because the command is without quotes, and don't work if I put quotes in it), but because I'm just assigning a variable maybe it's safe. Thanks anyway!

Comment: As a side note, if I don't single quote `SHELL`, but use the `-s` option, I can still use variables in the heredoc, and I access the variable with `\$1`. It also solves the issue for me.

Comment: Also, `-s` isn't specific to here documents; you can use it to pass arguments to an interactive shell

Comment: Good to know, that can help me automate interactive commands. In any case, using single quotes also worked, the problem was that I was accessing variables with `\$`, which is used when there are no quotes in the delimiter, but with single quotes the script inside is as is, so I just used `$`, which allows me to create variables in it, and is even better. So, I will go with your approach.

Comment: @LucasBasquerotto You could try `list_in=$(printf %q "$list")` -- the `%q` format will add quotes and/or escapes as appropriate based on the contents of the string. A warning, though: it quotes/escapes *appropriately for being parsed by bash*. If it's going to be interpreted by some other shell (e.g. if the default shell in your Docker container is [dash instead of bash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)), it may quote/escape in a format that other shell doesn't understand.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks, using `%q` also works. It seems `printf` is safe when assigning the value to variables, so I don't have to worry about a command in the argument of `printf` being executed in an assignment (like in `cmd_in=$(printf %q "$cmd")`, as opposed to just `$(printf %q "$cmd")`, that executes the command).